# why dynamic cascading dropdown states and city work for the 1st time just in angular?

Tags: angular

I tested to make `states` and `city` cascading dynamic dropdownlists, i created two `dropdownlist`, `state` and `city`, i want to populate `drowdownlist` with corresponding `cities` to `state` but it doesn't work, it just works for the 1st time.
I don't know how to fix this problem

**select.component.ts**

```
          ngOnInit(): void {
          }
        
        states:any=[
          {id: 1,name: "Maharasthra"},
          {id: 2,name: "West Bengal"}
        ];
        
        cities:any=[
          {id: 1,name: "Mumbai",state_id:1},
          {id: 1,name: "Pune",state_id:1},
          {id: 2,name: "Kolkata",state_id:2},
          {id: 2,name: "Howrah",state_id:2}
        ];
        
onSelect(state:any){
  this.cities = this.cities.filter((item:any) => item.state_id == state.target.value);
  console.log(state.target.value)
}
```

**select.component.html**

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="form-group">
     <label>states <span class="text-hightlight">*</span></label>
     <select  class="form-control" (change)="onSelect($event)">
        <option [value]="0">--select--</option>
        <option [value]="i.id" *ngFor="let i of states" >{{ i.name }}</option>
     </select>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
     <label>city <span class="text-hightlight">*</span></label>
     <select  class="form-control" >
        <option [value]="c.id" *ngFor="let c of cities">{{ c.name }}</option>
     </select>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: At this point: `(change)="onSelect($event)`, the code is trying to invoke `onSelect` with `$event`. The `state` that the user selected will be within the event. In the `onSelect` function, may I please know where this selected `state` is being used?

Comment: @jsN00b thx for your answer i edit my code `onSelect(state:any){
  this.cities = this.cities.filter((item:any) => item.id == state);
  alert(state);
} `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that you're overwriting your cities array. you can try something like:

```
      ngOnInit(): void {
      }
    
    states:any=[
      {id: 1,name: "Maharasthra"},
      {id: 2,name: "West Bengal"}
    ];
    
    allCities = [
      {id: 1,name: "Mumbai",state_id:1},
      {id: 1,name: "Pune",state_id:1},
      {id: 2,name: "Kolkata",state_id:2},
      {id: 2,name: "Howrah",state_id:2}
    ];
    cities = []
    
onSelect(state:any){
  this.cities = this.allCities.filter((item:any) => item.state_id == state.target.value);
  console.log(state.target.value)
}
```